# How to Create a List of Available Times after removing Downtimes from a Period

Tags: filter, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a grid which lists the Period (Start - End), and a list of Downtimes.

The downtimes are then sorted (to ensure chronological order based on the start time of the outage), using the following formula:

`=SORT(INDIRECT("B4:C"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX((B4:B12<>"")*ROW(B4:B12)))),1)`

After which I am trying to calculate the list of Available times (Uptimes).

Currently i have a mess of inflexible formulas as follows:

B26 `=IF(B14<B15,B14,C15)`

C26 `=IF(C14<C15,C14,B16)`

B27 `=C16`

C27 `=B17`

I am searching for either a universal single celled arrayformula, or a formula that can be dragged (down/across), that can calculate the list of Available times (Uptimes).

I am seeking formula solutions that will work in **both** Excel (Mac 2021) **and** Google Sheets.

See attached image:
[image]

EDIT:

Here is a google sheet that has some example data, and explanatory notes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t0XImtjP4RKeTdg3L97bjPzateUX2waHPhjf3nmSFIk/edit#gid=2100307022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i created (working in both Excel + Google Sheets) for cutting downtimes from a time period, to leave only the remaining uptimes.

Using the same cells and ranges as per the Question....

The original downtimes does not need to be in order, they are sorted in the intermediate table.

in cell B15:

```
=IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(B4:C12,(B4:B12<=C3)*(C4:C12>=B3))),"")
```

Then, create named ranges for the elements to be used in the formulas that will populate the remaining uptimes (this makes the formulas easier to edit as will be noted below):

`start` is the start time of the original time period (`B14`)

`end` is the end time of the original time period (`C14`)

`downstart` is the range of the start datetimes of the downtimes (`B15:B23`)

`downend` is the range of the end datetimes of the downtimes (`C15:C23`)

Then, to create/populate the list of the remaining uptimes, for the opening times, enter this formula into the first cell (B25) :

```
=IFERROR(IF((start>=MIN(downstart))*(end<=MAX(downend)),IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downstart)>0))-1),"",SMALL(downend,1+ROW()-25)),
IF((start>=MIN(downstart)),SMALL(downend,1+ROW()-25),
IF((end<=MAX(downend)),IF(ROW()=25,start,IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downstart)>0))),"",SMALL(downend,ROW()-25))),
IF(ROW()=25,start,SMALL(downend,ROW()-25))
))),"")
```

And for the ending times, enter this formula into the first cell (C25):

```
=IFERROR(IF((start>=MIN(downstart))*(end<=MAX(downend)),IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))-1),"",SMALL(downstart,2+ROW()-25)),
IF((start>=MIN(downstart)),IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))-1),end,SMALL(downstart,2+ROW()-25)),
IF((end<=MAX(downend)),IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))-1),end,SMALL(downstart,1+ROW()-25)),
IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))),end,SMALL(downstart,1+ROW()-25))
))),"")
```

Note: In both of these formulas, the number `25` is the row number of the first row where the results are to be populated, so if you have these results starting on a different row, just change the number `25` to your starting row. Due to use of named ranges, no other changes are necessary.

After entering the formulas, drag them both down to fill the remaining results.

For those with Excel 2019 or newer (or Google Sheets), you can use IFS instead. For the opening times, use this (in B25 ):

```
=IFERROR(IFS(
(start>=MIN(downstart))*(end<=MAX(downend)),(IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downstart)>0))-1),"",SMALL(downend,1+ROW()-25))),
(start>=MIN(downstart)),SMALL(downend,1+ROW()-25),
(end<=MAX(downend)),(IF(ROW()=25,start,IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downstart)>0))),"",SMALL(downend,ROW()-25)))),
(start<MIN(downstart))*(end>MAX(downend)),(IF(ROW()=25,start,SMALL(downend,ROW()-25)))
),"")
```

And, for the ending times use this (in C25):

```
=IFERROR(IFS(
(start>=MIN(downstart))*(end<=MAX(downend)),(IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))-1),"",SMALL(downstart,2+ROW()-25))),
(start>=MIN(downstart)),(IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))-1),end,SMALL(downstart,2+ROW()-25))),
(end<=MAX(downend)),(IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))-1),end,SMALL(downstart,1+ROW()-25))),
(start<MIN(downstart))*(end>MAX(downend)),(IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))),end,SMALL(downstart,1+ROW()-25)))
),"")
```

Again, drag them down to populate the remaining results.

**Explanation:**

`(IF(ROW()=(25+SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(downend)>0))-1),xxxxxx` styled sections of the formulas check if on certain row, so that can return specific results

`SMALL(named_range,ROW()-(25))` styled sections of the formulas uses the ROW with an offset (25, based on this examples starting row for the results) to increment the SMALL

**Both the nested IF and the IFS styled solutions are in the example file linked in the opening Question.**

Answer (score 0):

in GS try:

```
=FILTER(B3:C24; A3:A24="Period")
```

---

### update

B15:

```
=SORT(B4:C12)
```

B25:

```
=QUERY({C15:C23, B16:B24}, "where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: for some reason i clicked the page, and it accepted as solution (i think i fixed that), but actually it is not the solution i am looking for.

Comment: @MrShane can you elaborate why it does not work for you so I could fix my answer?

Comment: the top table is original data. the middle table is sorted (chronological order) downtimes. the bottom table need to calculate the uptime periods after the downtimes are removed.. for simplified example, if i have numbers 1-100, but i remove between 1-5 and 30-35 and all of 69, now i have 5.1-29.9 and 35.1-68 and 70-100. i say simplified because actually we are dealing with datetimes, and not whole or part numbers.

Comment: so, imagine a long piece of string, and i take pieces from it, now i have several pieces of string with gaps in it.

Comment: @MrShane answer updated

Comment: thank for the QUERY, however this does not "cut pieces out of the long string" i have added a google sheet link to help with providing solution.